# How to hook to custom javascript trigger when using IJavaScriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, protractor

We have this event define in our web application, that creates a custom trigger called `timelineEventClicked`

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
                    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);

                        ...//some manipulation here

                        $.event.trigger({
                            type: "timelineEventClicked",
                            sender: _timelineObject,
                            events: settings.events,
                            eventData: eventData
                        });
                    });
```

I would like to hook to this event  `timelineEventClicked` and get back the `eventData` using selenium or protractor by injecting

```
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.ExecuteScript(@"(function() {                       
                    document.addEventListener('timelineEventClicked', function(e) {
                        //Not sure what to do here to get back evendata
                })();"
                );
```

The problem is that it doesn't seems to recognize the event `timelineEventClicked` and not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retreive the event, store it in the global scope with the listener.
Then click the canvas to trigger the event and return the variable:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

// install the listener
executor.ExecuteScript(
  "$(document).on('timelineEventClicked', function(e){ window._evt=e; });");

// trigger the event
driver.FindElement(...).Click();

// return the event
var data = executor.ExecuteScript(@"return window._evt;");
```